# Flex preloader stuck on 17% when initializing the app

Tags: google-app-engine, apache-flex, preloader

I have a preloader downloading and intializing my app. the download phase is successfully complete but the initialize always stuck on 17% for about 1-3 minutes (it varies) and only then completing.

I tried to search for it and tried to:

1. put a version number in the index.html file and change it on each deployment like this:

   ```
   swfobject.embedSWF("Main.swf?ver=0.027", "flashContent", "100%", "100%", "10.2", null, null, {name:"flashContent"}, {"wmode" : "transparent"}, cb);
   ```
2. tried to user the flex analyzer to see which module is holding it down, but i couldnt succeed to work with it on the preloading phase (only after the app is loaded).

anything else i can do to locate the source of the problem?

UPDATE:
found that the problem might be regarding using gzip from the server when fetching the flex client. the problem is that im working with google app engine and they have a bug which says that you cant disable the gzip compression if your browser support this. in the other hand flex is forbidden the developer to disable gzip as well (if someone know how to disable it from the preloader please share). any idea is welcome.

UPDATE2:
the gzip didnt worked, so i kept searching and found out eventually that it hangs before nextFrame() is being called. currentFrame is always null in the systemManager and the ENTER_FRAME event is being fired one by one but without change on the currentFrame value. what can i do to find the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i found the answer. google is using chunked encoding to send static files (cant be changed) and the preloader thinks after the first chunk it finished downloading all the swf, thus stuck in the next phase.

to see my solution you can enter here, hope it will help someone:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1446930